# Rails form submitting nested fields twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a model called `@miniset`

It accepts nested attributes for `@scale` through the `@size` model, in it's new.html.erb form.

This was all working fine until recently it started submitting the nested information TWICE.

It creates a `@miniset` and a `@size` for it but then it creates another `@size` with the same information but missing the `:scale_id`.

I have looked around and am utterly at a loss as to why it has started doing this.

I don't really know which code to include here.

This is the log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FpDJeyhp8Qb17v6H6EF+ZXi0562cyNv6oV+yl/HrT8I=", "miniset"=>{"name"=>"Test please work", "quantity"=>"4", "material"=>"Hard Plastic", "sizes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"scale_id"=>"1"}}, "pcode"=>"", "release_date(1i)"=>"", "release_date(2i)"=>"", "release_date(3i)"=>"", "notes"=>""}, "Set Scale"=>{"#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Size:0x007ff9a9cd8728>"=>""}, "commit"=>"Add set"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'd59f28d384d62b71719dd845b4e5353cdd993016' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (5.6ms)  INSERT INTO "minisets" ("created_at", "material", "name", "notes", "pcode", "quantity", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 20:10:49 UTC +00:00], ["material", "Hard Plastic"], ["name", "Test Please Work"], ["notes", ""], ["pcode", ""], ["quantity", 4], ["updated_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 20:10:49 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "sizes" ("created_at", "miniset_id", "scale_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 20:10:49 UTC +00:00], ["miniset_id", 8], ["scale_id", 1], ["updated_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 20:10:49 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "sizes" ("created_at", "miniset_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 20:10:49 UTC +00:00], ["miniset_id", 8], ["updated_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 20:10:49 UTC +00:00]]
```

This is the bit of the form that deals with size/scale:

```
<%= f.fields_for :sizes do |size_fields| %>
      <%= size_fields.label :scale_id, simple_pluralize(@miniset.scales.count, 'Scale') %>
      <%= hidden_field "Set Scale", @miniset.sizes %>
      <div class = "form-inline"><%= size_fields.select :scale_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Scale.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @miniset.scales.map(&:id)}) %>
      <% end %></div>
```

In my mindsets_controller I have

```
def create
    @miniset = Miniset.new(miniset_params)
    @size = @miniset.sizes.build
    if @miniset.save
      redirect_to @miniset
    else
      render 'new'
end
```

and below I have the `mini set_params`

```
def miniset_params
      params.require(:miniset).permit(:name, :release_date, :material, :pcode, :notes, :quantity, sizes_attributes: [:id, :scale_id, :miniset_id])
end
```

If you think you could help isolate the problem but need other code then please let me know and I'll edit this. Erk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting sizes_attributes from the Form AND then building another `Size` child in the Controller before saving.

You'll notice the 2nd Size that is saved is missing a "scale_id", so it's not the same Size as the one from the Form.

```
def create
    @miniset = Miniset.new(miniset_params) # Miniset AND Size initialized from params
    @size = @miniset.sizes.build # ANOTHER Size initialized, remove this line
    if @miniset.save
      redirect_to @miniset
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

The issue is this: `@size = @miniset.sizes.build` which is not necessary as you are creating the children via nested_attributes.

Comment: FANtastic. Thank you so much. I don't know when that happened. I need the @size in the new action but not the create but at some point I must have got confused. Works a treat now. A++

Comment: Just a FYI, you probably don't need @size in the new, if you are not using @size in your view. You could just build a size for the new Miniset and that also will do. I try to tell ppl, only create variables when you will use them otherwise it's a waste. You could just do `@miniset.sizes.build`, because it's all contained within the @miniset. If you do something WITH that size after it's built, you could do `size = @miniset.sizes.build`, where it's a local variable (No @), and not an instance (@) variable. ONLY use @ when you use that variable in the view. Hope that helps too!

Comment: On closer look I don't have @size in the new action I just have this `def new
    @miniset = Miniset.new 
    @miniset.sizes.build
end`

Comment: Sweeeet! Glad I could help!